# Upload Image using blackberry

Tags: image, blackberry, file-upload, blackberry-simulator

I want to upload an image in blackberry simulator using MultipartPostData, the following is my code but it does not seem to work. I have also signed my .cod file. Can anyone help me please?

```
public void postData(String Url, bytes[] data)
{
 if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()){
 Url=Url+";deviceSide=true";
}
HttpConnection httpConn=null;
OutputStream os=null;
InputStream is=null;
String url=Url;
try {
   PostData form = new MultipartPostData(MultipartPostData.DEFAULT_CHARSET, false) ;
   byte [] postData = data;
form.setData(postData);

      httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
      httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
   httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "BlackBerry");
   httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
   httpConn.setRequestProperty("MIME-Type", "Image/Jpeg");
      httpConn.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(postData.length));
      httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

      os =httpConn.openOutputStream();
      os.write(form.getBytes());

    //read response
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    is = httpConn.openDataInputStream();
    int chr;
    while ((chr = is.read()) != -1)
      sb.append((char) chr);

    System.out.println("Result................................ " + sb.toString());
    String result=sb.toString();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
finally {
    try{
        if(is!= null)
          is.close();
        if(os != null)
          os.close();
if(httpConn != null)
 httpConn.close();
 } catch(Exception e1){
        System.out.println(e1.toString());
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Actually the MultipartPostData should construct the post data with the boudary and the "Content-Disposition" lines.

Did you find any way to perform your request ? I am trying to do same thing and cannot pass any data to the server (the server is seeing only an empty array of data in the post).

Answer (score 2):

//you must have a bundary format post data, the .cod file must be work on the simulator

```
httpConn = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();
                httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);          
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("user-agent", "BlackBerry");    
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy");

            os = httpConn.openOutputStream();
            //os.write(form.getBytes());

            byte[] fileBytes = {1,2,3,4}; //retrieve file bytes with your own code                

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bos.write(("\r\n--" + "----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy" + "\r\n").getBytes());
       bos.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mifoto\"; filename=\"leo.gif\"\r\n").getBytes());
       bos.write(("Content-Type: image/gif\r\n\r\n").getBytes());
            bos.write(fileBytes);
       bos.write(("\r\n--" + "----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy" + "--\r\n").getBytes());

            os.write(bos.toByteArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you call `MultipartPostData.setData()`, it overwrites any Content-Disposition data you have set with `MultipartPostData.append()`.

leonel's answer works or you can use Vlad Patryshev's [ClientHttpRequest](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/17679/1954) class.