# How to stream video from blackberry to Browser

Tags: blackberry, video-streaming

I am creating an application which streams a live feed of the blackberry screen from a blackberry device to a web browser. This should allow a user to view the screen of the blackberry from the browser. Could someone suggest a stepwise method to do this?

Comment: can you explain it bit clearly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this method, [public static void screenshot(Bitmap bitmap)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html#screenshot%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap%29).

Documentation says that it takes a screenshot of the entire screen and saves it into a [Bitmap](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html), if supported by IT policy and/or application control. If the method works then it is possible to broadcast the screencast of a device by:

- Continuously taking screenshot (maintaining feasible interval) and
- Sending them to some server/destination (image compression can be applied before sending).

---

> Multipart Post/ Image Upload Issue - The following links may be
>   helpful.
>
> [BlackBerry Multipart POST Demo - Github](https://github.com/cleverua/blackberry_multipart_post)
>
> [HTTP POST Multipart file upload in JavaME - Nokia Developer](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME)
>
> [Upload Image in BlackBerry - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447872/upload-image-using-blackberry)
>
> [Posting Data via Http from Blackberry](http://blog.copyninja.info/2009/09/posting-data-via-http-from-blackberry.html)

Comment: This is one of the options I've already explored. My problem is that I am unable to make the POST request after taking a screenshot. I've tried many code samples for making Multipart POST requests but none of them work..

Comment: I have added some links regarding Multipart Post/Image Upload issue. Those may be helpful.